# How to query a table for data from 2 date ranges

Tags: sql-server

Im wanting to compare data from 2 different date ranges. I want the data to be shown in the same dataset with different columns from daterange1 and daterange2. Here is what I have now:

```
SELECT l1.Name, t1.SectionID, 
SUM(SectionItems) AS ItemCount, 
SUM(SectionSales) AS Sales, 
SUM(SectionCost) AS Cost, 
(((SUM(SectionSales) - SUM(SectionCost))/ SUM(SectionSales)) * 100) AS Margin
FROM StoreSectionSales t1
JOIN Sections l1 ON l1.SectionID = t1.SectionID AND l1.StoreID = t1.StoreID
WHERE TimeID <= (SELECT TimeID FROM Time WHERE FactDate = '11/15/2015') 
    AND TimeID <= (SELECT TimeID FROM Time WHERE FactDate = '11/15/2016') 
    AND t1.StoreID <> 08
GROUP BY t1.SectionID, l1.Name
ORDER BY t1.SectionID
```

Here is what the results look like:

```
Name      SectionID ItemCount   Sales   Cost    Margin
section1    1         1         100       1     100
section2    2         2         100       1     100
```

I would like to run the query from 2 different date ranges then add columns for Item Count sales cost and margin to the result set, adding them to the respective Section. I have tried a sub query however this adds all of the data together then apply that data to all rows.

Thanks.

Comment: Please post what you want your results to look like.

Comment: The results would have the columns: Name, SectionID, ItemCount1, Sales1, Cost1, Margin1, ItemCount2, Sales2, Cost2, Margin2. The columns with 1 would be from the first date range and the columns with 2 would be from the second date range

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select time1.name, time1.sectionID, 
time1.ItemCount as ItemCount1, time1.Sales as Sales1, 
time2.ItemCount as ItemCount2, time2.Sales as Sales2
from
(SELECT l1.Name, t1.SectionID, 
    SUM(SectionItems) AS ItemCount, 
    SUM(SectionSales) AS Sales, 
    SUM(SectionCost) AS Cost, 
    (((SUM(SectionSales) - SUM(SectionCost))/ SUM(SectionSales)) * 100) AS Margin
    FROM StoreSectionSales t1
    inner join Sections l1 ON l1.SectionID = t1.SectionID AND l1.StoreID = t1.StoreID
    WHERE TimeID <= (SELECT TimeID FROM Time WHERE FactDate = '11/15/2015') 
    AND t1.StoreID <> 08
GROUP BY t1.SectionID, l1.Name) time1
inner join 
(SELECT l1.Name, t1.SectionID, 
    SUM(SectionItems) AS ItemCount, 
    SUM(SectionSales) AS Sales, 
    SUM(SectionCost) AS Cost, 
    (((SUM(SectionSales) - SUM(SectionCost))/ SUM(SectionSales)) * 100) AS Margin
    FROM StoreSectionSales t1
    inner join Sections l1 ON l1.SectionID = t1.SectionID AND l1.StoreID = t1.StoreID
    WHERE TimeID <= (SELECT TimeID FROM Time WHERE FactDate = '11/15/2016') 
        AND t1.StoreID <> 08
    GROUP BY t1.SectionID, l1.Name) time2 on time1.name = time2.name
order by time1.sectionID;
```

I left out some columns, but you get the idea.